# Black dimond question mark character in text files

Tags: text, character-encoding, tex

I am working with .tex files. If I copy some content from a notepad txt file onto the .tex file, on gedit, .tex files show black diamond shaped question marks in places where there were quotation marks or hyphens. I use gedit on ubuntu machine. How can I get rid of those shapes?

Comment: When you say Notepad, do you mean you are cutting and pasting content from Windows Notepad into a `.tex` file, then opening that `.tex` file in Linux?

Comment: Yes. From notepad I paste the content onto a tex file opened in notepad++, and also open it in gedit on Linux

Answer (score 3):

This is really just an embedded `a0`.  You can get rid of it with `sed`.

```
<YOURFILE sed 's/\xa0//g' > YOURFILE.FIXED
```

(or use `sed -i` to change the file in place.)

Answer (score 0):

The black diamonds appear because the editor you are using cannot render the characters in the text you are trying to display.  You could try a better editor like emacs or vi and load up the file from there and then copy and paste within the editor.

Comment: Even in vim and nano same character appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the font in gedit to one that has more complete support of the Unicode character sets. For example, you could try the [Ubuntu font family](http://font.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: It is not a font problem. If I compile the latex files, blank spaces appear at the places where there were black diamond question marks.